# Erlang - How to print list results on a new line?

Tags: erlang, list-comprehension

I have the following function where it takes a list of integers and returns only the even numbers within that list.

```
 even_print(List)->
          [X||X <- List, even == even_odd(X)].
```

How can I print the results in a new line like this:

```
216> seq_erlang:even_print([2,4,5]).
2
4
```

instead of this:

```
216> seq_erlang:even_print2([2,4,5]).
[2,4]
```

I have used `io:format("~p~n",X)` inside my list comprehension but my variable X becomes unbound of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
even_print(List)->
 [io:format("Printing ~p ~n",[X])|| X <- List, even == even_odd(X)].
```

Now try:

```
217> seq_erlang:even_print([2,4,5]).
Printing 2 
Printing 4 
[ok,ok]
```